# Where is the terminal server client (tsclient?)

Tags: 11.10, rdp, tsclient

I accidentally done partial upgrade and there was Gnome3 ppa and broke my unity. After failed attempt to rescue (ppa-purge et al) I decided the only solution was to upgrade to Oneiric beta2 (fresh install is not an option). Now In Natty I was using terminal server client to do remote connection (mostly RDP). I cannot find tsclient in package. I have googled with no avail. I have tested Remmina and the other Ubuntu RDP packages and I'm dissatisfied at best. Is there a way to install terminal server client?
Did Oneiric abandon it? What is their proposed alternative?
IMHO terminal server client is the best RDP client (GUI)
Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm using [Remmina](http://remmina.sourceforge.net/) from much time and I'm satisfied of it, comparing with tsclient it's modern and easy to save and group connections. I think it will become the standard RDP client.

You can also integrate it in Unity: [Remmina Unity Launcher](http://code.google.com/p/remmina-unity-launcher/)

As an alternative, you can also launch **rdesktop** directly from the [command line](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rdesktop).

Comment: Hi Pisu,
The problem with Remmina is some quirks that are yet not fixed or not clear somewhere. Yes it is modern and cool but a bit unstable yet. For example, It gives bizzare actions when I use keyboard shortcuts in remote computer until I manually refresh. That is really annoying!

Answer (score 8):

It looks like TSClient has been [removed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ugr-meta/+bug/799068) in Oneiric. Due to problems with compatibility to GTK3.

They propose another application: Vinagre.

tsclient will install with errors, but does work.
Download deb file from ubuntu and install

http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/i386/tsclient/download

Tested and working on 11.10 with Unity and Gnome 3

Comment: Thanks Dan, Viagre is ugly!
I will have to live with Remmina and may be file a bug than going to ugly vinagre (I actually uninstalled it!)